# Async/Await/then in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I have a flutter application where I am using the SQFLITE plugin to fetch data from SQLite DB. Here I am facing a weird problem.  As per my understanding, we use either async/await or then() function for async programming. 
Here I have a db.query() method which is conducting some SQL queries to fetch data from the DB. After this function fetches the data, we do some further processing in the .then() function. However, in this approach, I was facing some issues.  From where I am calling this getExpensesByFundId(int fundId)function, it doesn't seem to fetch the data properly. It's supposed to return Future> object which will be then converted to List when the data is available. But when I call it doesn't work.

However, I just did some experimentation with it and added "await" keyword in front of the db.query() function and somehow it just started to work fine.  Can you explain why adding the await keyword is solving this issue? I thought when using .then() function, we don't need to use the await keyword.

Here are my codes:

```
Future<List<Expense>> getExpensesByFundId(int fundId) async {
    Database db = await database;

    List<Expense> expenseList = List();

   // The await in the below line is what I'm talking about

    await db.query(expTable,where: '$expTable.$expFundId = $fundId')
        .then((List<Map<String,dynamic>> expList){
      expList.forEach((Map<String, dynamic> expMap){
        expenseList.add(Expense.fromMap(expMap));
      });
    });
    return expenseList;
  }
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In simple words:

`await` is meant to interrupt the process flow until the `async` method has finished.
`then` however does not interrupt the process flow (meaning the next instructions will be executed) but enables you to run code when the `async` method is finished.

In your example, you cannot achieve what you want when you use `then` because the code is not 'waiting' and the `return` statement is processed and thus returns an empty list.

When you add the `await`, you explicitly say: 'don't go further until my `Future` method is completed (namely the `then` part).

You could write your code as follows to achieve the same result using only `await`:

```
Future<List<Expense>> getExpensesByFundId(int fundId) async {
    Database db = await database;

    List<Expense> expenseList = List();

    List<Map<String,dynamic>> expList = await db.query(expTable,where: '$expTable.$expFundId = $fundId');
    expList.forEach((Map<String, dynamic> expMap) {
        expenseList.add(Expense.fromMap(expMap));
    });

    return expenseList;
}
```

You could also choose to use only the `then` part, but you need to ensure that you call `getExpensesByFundId` properly afterwards:

```
Future<List<Expense>> getExpensesByFundId(int fundId) async {
    Database db = await database;

    List<Expense> expenseList = List();
    
    return db.query(expTable,where: '$expTable.$expFundId = $fundId')
        .then((List<Map<String,dynamic>> expList){
      expList.forEach((Map<String, dynamic> expMap){
        expenseList.add(Expense.fromMap(expMap));
      });
    });
}

// call either with an await
List<Expense> list = await getExpensesByFundId(1);
// or with a then (knowing that this will not interrupt the process flow and process the next instruction
getExpensesByFundId(1).then((List<Expense> l) { /*...*/ });
```

Comment: WOW!!! what a wonderful explanation. Right after I submitted the question i figured out that the function was returning an empty list and that was causing all the problems.  But your answer made it even more clear.
But I have a further question. if await keyword interrupts the process flow, doesn't it freeze the app? I mean since Dart runs on single thread doesn't that block the entire thread?

Comment: It can. You have to understand how the Event Loop works (https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop) and how `Isolates` can help you in some cases.

Comment: 3 hours searching to get this explanation you said in the first 3 sentences, but I have the same question Javaland asked, so (await) keyword will freeze the app until it executes her code?

Comment: I don’t understand, so if await blocks code what is the whole purpose of it? Why not just use normal code which also blocks? I understand for using it where you want other unrelated code to run before results come from the future. Or is it because the function is only available as a future so there’s no other choice if you really need the results before proceeding

Comment: `await` is only used with `async` functions, who, as the name implies, runs asynchronously. Therefore it is up to you to chose if you want to wait the asynchronous code to finish before continuing (with `await`) or not.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the above answers.

Flutter Application is said to be a step by step execution of code, but it's not like that.
There are a lot of events going to be triggered in the lifecycle of applications like Click Event, Timers, and all. There must be some code that should be running in the background thread.

**How background work execute:**

So there are two `Queues`

1. Microtask Queue
2. Event Queue

`Microtask Queue` runs the code which not supposed to be run by any event(click, timer, etc). It can contain both sync and async work.

`Event Queue` runs when any external click event occurs in the application like Click event, then that block execution done inside the event loop.

The below diagram will explain in detail how execution will proceed.

[image]

**Note:** At any given point of application development Microtask queue will run then only Event Queue will be able to run.

Comment: Can you please suggest any blogs where I can read this in detail..

Comment: @PoojaKamath [this old event-loop article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170704074724/https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop) explains the details of event vs. microtask queues

Answer (score 1):

When making class use `async` for using `await` its simple logic to make a wait state in your function until your data is retrieve to show.

Example: 1) Its like when you follow click button 2) Data first store in database than `Future` function use to retrieve data 3) Move that data into variable and than show in screen 4) Variable show like increment in your following/profile.

And `then` is use one by one step of code, store data in variable and then move to next.

Example: If I click in follow button until data store in variable it continuously retrieve some data to store and not allow next function to run, and if one task is complete than move to another.

Same as your question i was also doing experiment in social media flutter app and this is my understanding. I hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

And this is how I would do it:

```
  var db = await openDatabase('my_db.db');
  List<Expense> expenseList = [];
  fillExpenses(1, db, expenseList); 


fillExpenses(int fundId, Database db, List<Expense> expenseList){    
   db.query(expTable,where: '$expTable.$expFundId = $fundId')
       .then((List<Map<String,dynamic>> expList){
       expList.forEach((Map<String, dynamic> expMap){
          expenseList.add(Expense.fromMap(expMap));
       });
   });
}
```

The point is to not return any value and avoid async-await in both the function that does the job and the function that calls it.

Answer (score -3):

A Flutter question from an answer from your answer.
await is meant to interrupt the process flow until the async method has finished. then however does not interrupt the process flow but enables you to run code when the async method is finished. So, I am asking diff. between top down & bottom down process in programming.

Comment: this answer could be more clarified and optimized

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).