# Using Flutter and Dart, how can I get this Future to work?

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I know that there are other ways of achieving this, but I want to use a Future via initState() to obtain a List using SharedPreferences. The following illustrates what I want to achieve, but it does not work as required, because the Future returns immediately before completing the task.

How should this be structured?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  SharedPreferences _prefs;
  String _sMessage = "No response from getting params";
  List<String> _lsCategories;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initPreferences().then((_) {
      try {
        _lsCategories = _prefs.getStringList("categories") ?? [];
        debugPrint("Categories = $_lsCategories");
        _sMessage = "Categories loaded OK";
      } catch (vError) {
        _sMessage = ("Error loading categories = $vError");
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  Future<void> _initPreferences() async {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      _prefs = prefs;
      debugPrint("Preferences initialized OK");
    }).catchError((vError) {
      debugPrint("Error initializing preferences = ${vError.toString()}");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_sMessage,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red[500],
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Future Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: "Flutter Future Test"),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

Comment: your `_initPreferences` method does not return any `Future`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `_initPreferences` method to the following:

```
Future<void> _initPreferences() async {
  try {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _prefs = prefs;
    debugPrint("Preferences initialized OK");
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint("Error initializing preferences = ${e.toString()}");
  }
}
```

The issue is that when using `.then()` on a Future you are not waiting for that future to finish, using `await` does wait.

Comment: not really, `await` is the same thing as using `then` - i mean you can achieve the same result either by using `await` or `then`

Comment: not really, `await` suspends execution `then` does not. Good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54515559/5608661

Comment: you can achieve the same result either by using `await` or `then` - `await` is nothing but "syntactic sugar" - basically OP does not return correct `Future` from `_initPreferences` method

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
Future<void> _initPreferences() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance().catchError((vError) { 
          debugPrint("Error initializing preferences = ${vError.toString()}");
    };
    debugPrint("Preferences initialized OK");
}
```