# Async function doesn't await

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to upload an image to firebase storage but when I called the function, await is not executed to get the url. What am I missing in this?

Looking at this other topic I've got that the problem may be the "then", but how can I set the code to await the url?

[Async/Await/then in Dart/Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515186/async-await-then-in-dart-flutter)

```
Future < String > uploadImage(File imageFile) async {
  String _imageUrl;
  StorageReference ref =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(firebaseUser.uid.toString());

  await(ref.putFile(imageFile).onComplete.then((val) {
    val.ref.getDownloadURL().then((val) {
      _imageUrl = val;
      print(val);
      print("urlupload");
    });
  }));

  print(_imageUrl);
  print("urlnoupload");

  return _imageUrl;

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had async/await when you didn't need it because you were capturing value in the `then` function

```
Future<String> uploadImage(File imageFile) async {
  String _imageUrl;
  StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(firebaseUser.uid.toString());
  return ref.putFile(imageFile).onComplete.then((val) {
      return val.ref.getDownloadURL()
  }).then((_imageUrl) {
      return _imageUrl;
  });
},
```

Comment: It worked Aaron, thanks, I think I get the "then" now.
Just one more thing, why you need to set a return 3 times?