# Flutter future function

Tags: flutter

i am trying to get some data from firebase and than use that data to take other information. I am trying to do it using a future function. The problem is that everything works fine but the list comes out empty at the end and i dont know how to make it wait until the values have been added to the list and than appear. As you can see in this photo, the list comes out empty and than after print out the results and when you look in the code its vice versa. I tried some stuff using the await but with no success.
https://gyazo.com/4dc9b3b4d459270c7c4bf146baa6ae25
What do you guys think?

```
Future <DataSnapshot> getData()async{
  List lists = [];
  await databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    
    Map < dynamic, dynamic > values = snapshot.value;
      values.forEach((key, values)async {
       
        await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Users/" + values["UID"].toString() + "/Name").once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
           
            lists.add(snapshot.value);
            print(snapshot.value);
         
          }); }, );
          
          }
          
          );

          print(lists);
}
```

Comment: please add the code directly inside your question instead of a screenshot, using ``` ```

Comment: To answer your question, it may be because you are using both await and then?  Make a choice but don't use both!

Comment: i added the code

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a choice between using 'await' and 'then' keyword, using both is not recommended. See [Async/Await/then in Dart/Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515186/async-await-then-in-dart-flutter) for detailed explanation about the difference.

```dart
Future <List<Map < dynamic, dynamic >>> getData() async {
  List<Map < dynamic, dynamic >> lists = [];
  DataSnapshot snapshot = await databaseReference.once();
  Map < dynamic, dynamic > values = snapshot.value;
  await values.forEach((key, values) async {
      DataSnapshot snapshotUser = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Users/" + values["UID"].toString() + "/Name").once();
      lists.add(snapshotUser.value);
      print(snapshotUser.value);
   }
   print(lists);
   return lists;
}
```

Comment: so i should remove the avait?

Comment: yes try first by removing the await keyword, and if it doesnt work try with await and getting rid of then (you will have to put the result of await in a variable, like var mydata = await databaseReference... ), it will work for sure.

Comment: ok  so i  remove all the awaits and it doesnt work, so it must be from the than but i dont know  what to put instead of it

Comment: i mean the parts after 'then' what do i do with them

Comment: I have updated my answer with await, give it a try

Comment: https://gyazo.com/338b6699dffa8d0682e85e6fe9aa142a any idea why i get this?

Comment: so it's a Map < dynamic, dynamic > and not a string, try again with Map < dynamic, dynamic > instead of String

Comment: it doesnt give an error now but unfortunately it's the same result...

Comment: list comes out first and than the names.. it is really frustrating

Comment: try with await before values.forEach

Comment: it has something to do with that for sure

Comment: i mean i need a way to wait for that foreach to end

Comment: potentially the program uses the first snapshot variable instead of snapshotUser, try with renaming the variable