# contact_services getContactsForPhone returing Future<dynamic> instead of String - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, contacts

I am trying to get `Contact` using the function `getContactsForPhone`

```
   getName()async{
    number = '123-456-7890'
    return await ContactsService.getContactsForPhone(number).then((value) =>  value.elementAt(0).displayName.toString());
  }
```

but I am getting `Future<dynmaic>` instead of `.displayName` which is supposed to be String

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54515559/13701546

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing it up two way's to use Futures:

- You can use `await` keyword to await for the conclusion.
- You can use the `then` method to have a callback when the Future ends.

You need to choose one and stick with it. Using the `await` is always preferable because it makes the code more readable and avoids some [callback hells](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25098066/10746978).

In your case:

```
Future<String> getName() async {
    number = '123-456-7890'
    Iterable<Contact> myIterable = await ContactsService.getContactsForPhone(number);
    List<Contact> myList = myIterable.toList();
    return myList[0].displayName.toString()
  }
```

Which should return the DisplayName you wanted.

Remember to also use the `await` keyword from the outside, wherever you call this function.

You can read more about Future and Asynchronous code [here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply, I copied your code exactly but it's still returning the same thing, Future<dynamic>. @Naslausky

Comment: @AnanSaadi, I've edited my answer in two points: 1) The return type should be Future<String>, and 2) you need to use the ```await``` when calling this function aswell.

Comment: Thank you @Naslausky, it's finally working :D