# Flutter rebuilds widget without waiting for code execution

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function to upload image to the server. However the widgets starts rebuilding while the image is being uploaded and does not execute code after image is uploaded.

```
InkWell(
  child: Icon(
    Icons.camera,
    size: 50,
    color: Colors.red[400],
  ),
  onTap: () {
    _imageFile =
        _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    _imageFile.then((file) async {
      if (file != null) {
        fileName = file.path.toString();
        var res = await Auth.uploadImage(file);
        print("Response for image upload is : ");
        print(res);
        await setUserData();
      }
    });
  },
)
```

This is the output on the console from print statements

```
I/flutter (10171): Calling build Method
I/Timeline(10171): Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:68831133
I/flutter (10171): Uploading image to server
I/flutter (10171): Calling build Method
I/flutter (10171): Image uploaded successfully
```

As can be seen above no other code is executed and the widget has rebuilt itself. What am I possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_imageFile = _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);`
its not right, `getImage` is an `Asynchronous`  function so you need to wait for it to finish.

do this -  `_imageFile = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);`

If you want to use `then` do it like this,
`_picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera).then((image)...your code...)`

Comment: Thank you. Changing it to async/await instead of 'then' works.

Comment: you can also use ```then``` but your ```then``` implementaion is a bit wrong. i have updated my answer so it will work with then.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you're using `_imageFile = _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);` the `_imageFile` result will come in the future and your next code is executed.

You can fixed the problem either using `await`:

```
 onTap: () async {
    _imageFile =
        await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (_imageFile != null) {
        fileName = file.path.toString();
        var res = await Auth.uploadImage(file);
        print("Response for image upload is : ");
        print(res);
        await setUserData();
    }
  },
```

Or keep using `then` with a slight change:

```
  onTap: () {
    _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera)
           .then((file) async {
             if (file != null) {
               fileName = file.path.toString();
               var res = await Auth.uploadImage(file);
               print("Response for image upload is : ");
               print(res);
               await setUserData();
           }
        });
  },
```

See explanation about `await & then`: [Async/Await/then in Dart/Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515186/async-await-then-in-dart-flutter/54515559)

Comment: Thank you. I'm using async/await. You can edit your answer to change all references of "file" to "_imageFile".